# Is $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^3+2x+2)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Is $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^3+2x+2)$ a field?

Since $x^3+2x+2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ (it has a root in $\mathbb{F}_5$), I don't no any other way to test this...

Comment: Such a factor ring is a field if and only if the ideal is a maximal ideal. If the ideal in question is maximal, then the polynomial generating it must be irreducible. As you say, it is not. So your proof is fine. I see no need to say anything else in your proof.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $x^{3}+2x+2$ is reducible, then $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]/(x^{3}+2x+2)$ has zero divisors. Can a field have zero divisors?

Comment: and if it is irreductible ? we need to prove that $P(x) \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/Q(x) \implies gcd(P(x),Q(x)) = 1 \implies a(x) P(x) + b(x) Q(x) = 1$ with $a(x) \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]/Q(x)$ hence $P(x) \equiv (a(x))^{-1} \pmod{Q(x)}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: if the polynomial is irreducible, then it generates a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]$, so the quotient ring must be a field.

Comment: ok but what is the simplest proof of that ? with the $gcd$ ($\sim$ what I wrote ?)

Comment: Well, there are *many* proofs of this general fact. Your argument looks mostly correct, though you might want to flesh out a few details, and carefully distinguish between elements of $\mathbb{F}_{5}[x]$ and elements of the quotient.

Comment: wait how can I show that $x^3+2x+2$ is reducible?

Comment: Note that $1$ is a root of $x^3+2x+2$, so $(x-1)$ divides $x^{3}+2x+2$. One can also see that $3$ is a root of $(x^{3}+2x+2)$, so $(x-3)$ divides $x^{3}+2x+2$. These are the only roots over $\mathbb{F}_{5}$, so in fact, one of them must be a repeated root. With small effort, one can show that $(x^{3}+2x+2)$ factors as $(x-1)^{2}(x-3)$.

Comment: I see. So the zero divisors are not invertible? (not directly related to this, just wondering...)

Comment: @nashvillerosie: yep. This is true in any ring. Try proving this - it's a good exercise! If you get stuck, feel free to ask for more help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f \in K[x]$ can be factored as $f=gh$ with $g,h$ not constant and coprime, then
$$
\frac{K[x]}{(f)} \cong \frac{K[x]}{(g)} \times \frac{K[x]}{(h)}
$$
and so cannot be a field because a product of two rings is never a field: $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$.

Comment: sorry, why it cannot be field ? (I don't see where are the zero divisors here)

Comment: the direct product for rings always means that the multiplication is term by term ? it makes sense ok.